# Get element by id in javascript without having any form tag on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am wondering if it is possible to get the element by id in javascript when there is no form tag available.

I am using the following command to get the text box value but i am getting error message 'null or undefined'. This works fine if i use proper form tag on asp.net page.

```
var _txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
```

Is there any other way of getting textbox values in javascript (when there is no form,body and header tag in asp.net page)

Here is the code

```
enter code here
```

```
    <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" ID="ddl" Height="20px" 
        Width="215px" ValidationGroup="aa">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">--select--</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">item-1</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:dropdownlist>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="ddl" ErrorMessage="required" InitialValue="0" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="aa"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <br />
    <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="txt" ValidationGroup="aa" Width="140px"></asp:textbox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txt" ErrorMessage="required" InitialValue="" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="aa"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />

</div>

<div>
    <asp:validationsummary runat="server" ID="valSummary"
        HeaderText="Vendor Ref and Contact are required" ValidationGroup="aa" 
        CssClass="valsummary">
    </asp:validationsummary>
</div>


    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="DO" ValidationGroup="aa" 
    Width="118px" OnClientClick="Test2()"/>


<br />


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    function Test() {
        var _indx = document.getElementById('ddl');
        var _txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;

        if (_indx.selectedIndex == 0 || _txt == '') {
            document.getElementById('_div').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('_div').style.display = "block";
        }
        else {

            document.getElementById('_div').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('_div').style.display = "none";
        }

    }

    function Test2() {
        var _indx = document.getElementById('ddl');
        var _txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var msg_I = "........"
        var msg_II = "...."
        var msg_III = ".."


        if (_indx.selectedIndex == 0 && _txt == '') {
            txtHeader = msg_I
        }

        else if (_indx.selectedIndex == 0 && _txt != '') {

            txtHeader = msg_III
        }

        else if (_indx.selectedIndex != 0 && _txt == '') {

            txtHeader = msg_II
        }

        document.getElementById('<%= valSummary.ClientID %>').headertext = txtHeader;
    }  </script>
```

Comment: Have u tried to make use with client ID???

Comment: check the generated html, the input might have another ID

Comment: And check the placement of your script. It should either be placed after the input element or it should make use of `window.onload` or similar deferring event handler

Comment: check if, that line is called when page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var _txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;` to:

```
var _txt = document.getElementById("<%= txt.ClientID %>").value;
```

`ClientID` returns you generated ID to use in your client code.

Comment: got this error: Control 'ddl' of type 'DropDownList' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: @user1263981 check your open `div` tag.

Comment: @user1263981 this error got nothing to do with JavaScript. The error is very clear: if you want server side form element, you must have server side form. If you want just independant drop down use pure HTML and use AJAX to send its value to server.

Comment: so i need to use server form tag on the page?

Comment: @user1263981 if `form` tag wasn't generated automatically - yes.